# Inconsistent stringstream errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, stringstream

I'm having bizarre behavior with stringstreams. It seems that if I create two stringstreams, one will write correctly and one will raise errors. (test is a char*)

```
ostringstream s;
ostringstream d;
s<<test<<endl;
d<<test<<endl;
```

This gives the message "error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator<<'" for the last line.

```
ostringstream s;
ostringstream d;
d<<test<<endl;
d<<test<<endl;
```

This gives the message "error: invalid operands of types 'int' and 'const char*' to binary 'operator<<'" for both lines writing to d.

The two streams should be identical, so I don't know why d doesn't work. Switching the order of the declarations of s and d doesn't change anything. Anyone have an ideas why this might happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Please create the smallest possible complete program that demonstrates this error and post that. http://sscce.org

Comment: Can we see the exact details of the 'test' variable?  I ran this code, using string test = 'test'; and d<< test.c_str() << endl; and it had no problems.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I was stupidly shadowing a variable, fixed now! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same error when the variable `d` has already been declared so it has another type.

Comment: Oh, thank you!! Despite having more descriptive names in the actual program, I still managed to reuse the variable name. The world makes more sense now!

Comment: Sometimes compilers errors don't cover the real reason why they occur, so you should memorize the reason for such you had.

Comment: I think -Wall should warn you about this situation

Comment: For reference, -Wall didn't warn me, the error I posted was the entirety of what it gave me. But, I'll definitely consider a duplicate name sooner next time...